# How to automate commands in R?

Tags: r

I have a very basic question.

I am a new user of R, these days i am using one R package for my analysis, i have to run list of R commands of that package to get desired output.
I want to make my analysis pipeline and automate it so that i can do my work using one single R command with required parameters.

such type of work we do in shell scripts (where we add number of linux commands, awk/sed/perl lines

please provide me some link on how to do this, i would be thankful.

Comment: What do you mean by "automate" - are you already familiar with writing an R script (xxxx.r) with all your commands in it and then just doing `source('xxxx.r')` from within R? Or do you mean writing some function `doEverything(...)` that you want to then call with custom parameters from within R? In terms of executing R commands from a unix command line, look at [Rscript](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html) (it should have been installed with your R program): e.g. `Rscript -e 'runif(10)'`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose this was my analysis pipeline: I want to generate 10 numbers from the normal distribution with mean `MU` and standard deviation `SD` and then do something else with them:

```
MU <- 1  # the mean
SD <- .5 # standard deviation
NUMBER_TO_GENERATE <- 10

x <- rnorm(NUMBER_TO_GENERATE, mean=MU, sd=SD)
# ... more analysis here.
```

At the moment I copy-paste these commands into the R terminal.
There are a few ways to "automate" this.

#### 1. Write a function

I encompass my list of commands to execute into one big function, and put my parameters as function parameters:

```
myFunction <- function( MU, SD, NUMBER_TO_GENERATE ) {
    x <- rnorm(NUMBER_TO_GENERATE, mean=MU, sd=SD)
    # ... rest of analysis
}
```

Now within R I can just do `myFunction(1, .5, 10)`, reducing the number of commands I have to type to 1.

#### 2. Write a script

I could write a script file `myScript.r`. This is like a bash script except it's a list of R commands.

I can *either* put my original list of commands in there, Or I could put my function in there plus an additional statement at the bottom `myFunction(1,.5,10)`.

Then from *within* R, I can do:

```
source('myScript.r')
```

and it will run all the R commands in the script.

#### 3. From the shell

If you want to source this script from the shell, I'd suggest having a file `myScript.r` with the function inside it.

Then check out [Rscript](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html) (you can just `?Rscript` from within R). This comes installed R by default, and you use it for executing R commands from a unix/windows command line.

For example:

```
[mathematical.coffee@bar ~]$ Rscript -e '1+1'
[1] 2
```

In particular, you could combine methods 1) and 2) with `Rscript` to do something like:

```
[mathematical.coffee@bar ~]$ Rscript -e 'source("myScript.R"); myFunction( 1, .5, 10 )'
```

to run your function.

Or you could of course just include the `myFunction(1, .5, 10)` in your `myScript.R`, in which case you can just do `Rscript myScript.R`.

The advantage of the former is if you wanted to do shell scripting (I only mention this because you mentioned bash scripts in your question). In a *bash* script we could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
MU=1;
SD=.5;
NUM=10;

Rscript -e "source('myScript.r'); myFunction($MU,$SD,$NUM)"
```

However I'd argue for not mixing bash scripts with R scripts - as I mentioned before, I only mention this option because you mentioned bash/unix scripts in your question.

Comment: Thankyou mathematical.coffee for providing me such a beautiful explanations.

Comment: Why do advise against using R from a bash script?

Comment: @DunderChief I only advise against for this *particular* question, because the OP seemed a bit confused about all the options and I think one of the first two options was what they actually wanted. In general I have no issues with bash scripts and R (although I feel that you can usually achieve whatever functionality you want from the bash script, from within R (with an R script) instead).

Answer (score 2):

Functions are probably what you are looking for

```
foo <- function() {
 data <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=10:1)
 plot(data)

  # many more commands here
}
```

then you can just call `foo()` and all commands are run.

See the [R help](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions) for a more in depth informations.

Also `source()` might be of interest to you, see `?source`.

Comment: Thankyou jigr for getting me acquainted with function function()

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to run your program with Rscript. The arguments from the command line can be accessed with the function `args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)` (they are returned as a list)

e.g. using mathematical.coffee's example from above, your script would look like

Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
MU <- as.numeric(args[[1]])  # the mean
SD <- as.numeric(args[[2]]) # standard deviation
NUMBER_TO_GENERATE <- as.integer(args[[3]])

rnorm(NUMBER_TO_GENERATE, mean=MU, sd=SD)
doOtherStuff(x)
```

You could then call your function like `Rscript myscript.R 2.0 0.1 100`

If you want to do something fancier with the arguments (e.g. --filename) you can use the optparse library. http://www.r-bloggers.com/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/